# Is there a way to store the login input on my website?

Tags: javascript, html

Current [website](https://repl.it/@ze1598/LoginPageTutorial#index.html) doesn't really do anything except verify that the user inputs a specific username and password (username: user | password: web_dev).

I am trying to get it to store the username and password that the user inputs (maybe space for just 5?). All of this should erase or reset at the end of the session, nothing should save.

You can see the work on the hyperlink associated with website or here is another link: https://repl.it/@ze1598/LoginPageTutorial#index.html

Comment: Store it on your server. Use some program (really doesn't matter, but I pefer socket.io) to send the username to the server, and have all the usernames stored there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming you have a fixed set of username/passwords for the javascript and you just want to have the browser remember who the user is logged in as.

You could use one of these 2 options that don't require a backend to work:

(But please keep in mind that if the user/password combinations are stored inside your javascript - they can be read by anyone. No amount of obfuscation will solve that. You need a backend service/API to do actual user validation.)

**Cookies:**

Save:

```
document.cookie = "username=[]&password=[]";
```

Read:

```
var unparsedValue = document.cookie;
```

**localStorage** (from the window object: window.localStorage;)

Save:

```
localStorage.setItem('username', 'xxx');
localStorage.setItem('password', 'xxx');
```

Read:

```
var username = localStorage.getItem('username');
var password = localStorage.getItem('password');
```